# Workaround For MySQL Limit Function

Tags: mysql

My problem is best explained with a simple example: you line up all the children from a school in order of height. You want to break the line so that there are ten girls one side of the break. You don't know how many boys there will be because that will depend on their height.

My tables contain the geographical locations of usernames and each username can have more than one location. My code below finds usernames geographically closest to the input username using a self join. Normally such a join would include, `WHERE input_username <> input_username`, but I don't do this because I find it useful to have the `input_username` as part of the result set. However, I want to return 10 results APART from the input username.

If I understand correctly you can't do this with an sql limit clause because functions aren't allowed, but is there another way?

```
SELECT
t1.`username`,
t2.`title`,
t2.`lat`,
t2.`long`,
DATE_FORMAT(greatest(t1.`from`, t2.`from`), '%d/%m/%Y') `begin`,
DATE_FORMAT(least(t1.`to`, t2.`to`), '%d/%m/%Y') `end`,     
CAST((format((POWER(POWER(((t1.`long` - t2.`long`)*1112), 2) + POWER(((t1.`lat` - t2.`lat`)*1112), 2), 0.5)), 2))*0.1 AS DECIMAL(5,3)) distance,
t2.`username`,
IF(t2.`username`=t1.`username`, 'inquirer', 'neighbour') `type`
FROM
entries t1,
entries t2
WHERE
t1.`username` = username AND greatest(t1.`from`, t2.`from`) < least(t1.`to`, t2.`to`)
ORDER BY distance
LIMIT 10;
```

**Okay, is there a way to still order by distance but limit the result set so that it contains however many it needs to contain 10 'neighbour' 'type's?**

As it stands the output is limited to 10, some of which will be the 'inquirer', or input username, and some will be 'neighbours', or usernames near to the username doing the inquiring. I want to limit the result set so that there are 10 returns other than the input username.
The code above returns as follows:

```
username    title   lat long    begin   end distance    username    type
uv  "Title of entry 168"    51.595024   -0.128904   07/04/1919  07/04/1929  0.000   uv  inquirer
uv  "Title of entry 723"    51.610653   0.028761    26/09/1917  26/09/1927  0.000   uv  inquirer
uv  "Title of entry 444"    51.613369   0.034306    26/09/1917  21/10/1923  0.687   ee  neighbour
uv  "Title of entry 565"    51.588711   -0.129161   22/10/1919  07/04/1929  0.703   fh  neighbour
uv  "Title of entry 364"    51.601067   -0.121640   14/10/1923  07/04/1929  1.051   kg  neighbour
uv  "Title of entry 157"    51.620327   0.029985    12/12/1926  26/09/1927  1.084   ub  neighbour
uv  "Title of entry 1625"   51.608444   0.018629    30/08/1926  26/09/1927  1.153   wm  neighbour
uv  "Title of entry 554"    51.611248   -0.129845   07/04/1919  11/01/1928  1.807   gw  neighbour
uv  "Title of entry 1087"   51.599979   -0.113263   29/10/1924  07/04/1929  1.824   es  neighbour
uv  "Title of entry 1223"   51.620193   0.043415    26/09/1917  16/07/1922  1.944   bm  neighbour
```

The code proposed by fancypants returns as follows:

```
inusername  title   lat long    begin   end distance    outusername type    my_neighbour_counter
uv  "Title of entry 16" 51.649853   -0.012949   05/12/1925  26/09/1927  6.365   sh  neighbour   5
uv  "Title of entry 31" 51.569290   -0.206963   07/04/1919  02/07/1923  9.140   mj  neighbour   10
uv  "Title of entry 22" 51.532021   -0.223247   07/01/1925  07/04/1929  12.615  pn  neighbour   6
uv  "Title of entry 16" 51.649853   -0.012949   05/12/1925  07/04/1929  14.263  sh  neighbour   4
uv  "Title of entry 10" 51.473103   -0.203539   07/04/1919  21/05/1925  15.896  jx  neighbour   2
uv  "Title of entry 22" 51.532021   -0.223247   07/01/1925  26/09/1927  29.356  pn  neighbour   7
uv  "Title of entry 10" 51.473103   -0.203539   26/09/1917  21/05/1925  30.021  jx  neighbour   3
uv  "Title of entry 28" 51.354542   -0.259209   07/04/1919  31/08/1927  30.415  ui  neighbour   8
uv  "Title of entry 28" 51.354542   -0.259209   26/09/1917  31/08/1927  42.855  ui  neighbour   9
```

As can be seen, this is still limited to 10 rows. What I want to do is what Strawerberry does below, except as applied to my code.
The code that finally worked is below, followed by the resulting return. It could probably be done more efficiently. My thanks to fancyPants and Strawerberry.

```
SET @x := 'st';
SET @rank=0;
SELECT * FROM (SELECT *, if(inqu = neig, @rank:=@rank, @rank:=@rank + 1) `rank`
FROM (SELECT t1.`username` inqu, t2.`title`, t2.`lat`, t2.`long`,
        DATE_FORMAT(greatest(t1.`from`, t2.`from`), '%d/%m/%Y') `begin`,
        DATE_FORMAT(least(t1.`to`, t2.`to`), '%d/%m/%Y') `end`,
        CAST((format((POWER(POWER(((t1.`long` - t2.`long`) * 1112), 2) +
POWER(((t1.`lat` - t2.`lat`) * 1112), 2), 0.5)), 2)) * 0.1
AS DECIMAL (5 , 3 )) distance,
AS DECIMAL (5 , 3 )) distance,
        t2.`username` neig,
        IF(t2.`username` = t1.`username`, 'inquirer', 'neighbour') `type`
FROM
    entries t1, entries t2
WHERE
    t1.`username` = @x
        AND greatest(t1.`from`, t2.`from`) < least(t1.`to`, t2.`to`)
ORDER BY distance) m) n WHERE `rank` <= 10;
```

```
inqu    title   lat long    begin   end distance    neig    type    rank
st  "Title of entry 482"    51.511539   -0.034709   20/11/1976  21/11/1986  0.000   st  inquirer    0
st  "Title of entry 144"    51.523846   -0.188672   17/04/1959  17/04/1969  0.000   st  inquirer    0
st  "Title of entry 1034"   51.504379   -0.007122   22/02/1901  23/02/1911  0.000   st  inquirer    0
st  "Title of entry 956"    51.388729   -0.149454   26/09/1954  25/09/1964  0.000   st  inquirer    0
st  "Title of entry 1432"   51.391411   -0.149341   26/09/1954  08/07/1960  0.298   vg  neighbour   1
st  "Title of entry 1074"   51.519535   -0.182533   17/04/1959  29/04/1965  0.834   sw  neighbour   2
st  "Title of entry 742"    51.526321   -0.180818   03/08/1967  17/04/1969  0.916   ig  neighbour   3
st  "Title of entry 863"    51.519028   -0.179766   17/04/1959  05/04/1966  1.126   ad  neighbour   4
st  "Title of entry 728"    51.520554   -0.179007   21/10/1960  17/04/1969  1.135   pu  neighbour   5
st  "Title of entry 597"    51.526016   -0.177974   09/03/1966  17/04/1969  1.214   xj  neighbour   6
st  "Title of entry 1527"   51.514561   -0.045765   09/07/1986  21/11/1986  1.275   bh  neighbour   7
st  "Title of entry 892"    51.497967   -0.016889   26/01/1911  23/02/1911  1.299   kv  neighbour   8
st  "Title of entry 1004"   51.527172   -0.177020   17/04/1959  24/04/1960  1.347   li  neighbour   9
st  "Title of entry 1325"   51.517700   -0.199251   17/04/1959  11/01/1966  1.360   nj  neighbour   10
```

Answer (score 0):

Understood it like you want to have users and so on ordered by distance. It doesn't matter how many there are, but at max there should be 10 neighbours, right?

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT
    t1.`username`,
    t2.`title`,
    t2.`lat`,
    t2.`long`,
    DATE_FORMAT(greatest(t1.`from`, t2.`from`), '%d/%m/%Y') `begin`,
    DATE_FORMAT(least(t1.`to`, t2.`to`), '%d/%m/%Y') `end`,     
    CAST((format((POWER(POWER(((t1.`long` - t2.`long`)*1112), 2) + POWER(((t1.`lat` - t2.`lat`)*1112), 2), 0.5)), 2))*0.1 AS DECIMAL(5,3)) distance,
    t2.`username`,
    IF(t2.`username`=t1.`username`, 'inquirer', 'neighbour') `type`,
    @neighbour_counter := IF(t2.`username`=t1.`username`, @neighbour_counter, @neighbour_counter + 1) AS my_neighbour_counter
    FROM
    entries t1,
    entries t2,
    (SELECT @neighbour_counter := 1) my_variables
    WHERE
    t1.`username` = username AND greatest(t1.`from`, t2.`from`) < least(t1.`to`, t2.`to`)
    ORDER BY distance
) sq WHERE my_neighbour_counter <= 10
```

EDIT: Fixed error, was incrementing variable on inquirers rather than neighbours...

Comment: fancyPants, thanks, but this just gives the 10 nearest neighbours, which could be more simply done by excluding inquirers.

Comment: Then, ordered by distance, there are just 10 neighbours. If for example, again ordered by distance, there is one inquirer in your result, the query should return 11 rows. Please make sure, you have no typo or something.

Comment: Key of the query is `@neighbour_counter := IF(t2.`username`=t1.`username`, @neighbour_counter, @neighbour_counter + 1) AS my_neighbour_counter`. It's `@variable := IF(condition is true, then, else)`, in this case: same name, so the neighbour counter variable is not changed, if the names are not the same, the variable is incremented. And in the outer query you simply return the rows where the variable is <= 10

Comment: fancyPants - how do I re-enter code rather than comment? I want to show you what your code returned against the return from my original code.

Comment: You'd have to rephrase your question to make it absolutely clear. Sample data and desired output might help. Then click on reopen. Others will judge then if it will be reopened, if it's clear...it will be.

Comment: @user2790911 I looked at my code several times and I can absolutely not see an error in it. Please provide originial sample data, so I can have a try on it myself (preferably on http://sqlfiddle.com) And btw, it does exactly the same as Strawberrys code, except mine is adapted to the data you provided so far.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM children;
+------------+--------+--------+
| name       | height | gender |
+------------+--------+--------+
| Adam       |    126 | M      |
| Alice      |    103 | F      |
| Ben        |    106 | M      |
| Bernadette |    133 | F      |
| Charlie    |    101 | M      |
| Claire     |    102 | F      |
| Dan        |    139 | M      |
| Donna      |     96 | F      |
| Edward     |    141 | M      |
| Erica      |    119 | F      |
| Fiona      |    133 | F      |
| Frank      |    139 | M      |
| George     |    122 | M      |
| Georgina   |    134 | F      |
| Harriet    |    135 | F      |
| Henry      |    141 | M      |
| Inigo      |    139 | M      |
| Irene      |     96 | F      |
| Jessica    |    103 | F      |
| John       |    122 | M      |
| Kenneth    |    144 | M      |
| Kimberley  |    132 | F      |
| Lee        |    103 | M      |
| Lorraine   |    134 | F      |
| Michael    |    134 | M      |
| Michelle   |    102 | F      |
+------------+--------+--------+

SET @rank=0;

SELECT name
     , height
     , gender
  FROM 
     ( SELECT *
            , CASE WHEN gender = 'f' THEN @rank:=@rank+1 ELSE @rank:=@rank END rank 
         FROM children 
        ORDER 
           BY height
     ) m
 WHERE rank <= 10;
+------------+--------+--------+
| name       | height | gender |
+------------+--------+--------+
| Donna      |     96 | F      |
| Irene      |     96 | F      |
| Charlie    |    101 | M      |
| Michelle   |    102 | F      |
| Claire     |    102 | F      |
| Lee        |    103 | M      |
| Alice      |    103 | F      |
| Jessica    |    103 | F      |
| Ben        |    106 | M      |
| Erica      |    119 | F      |
| John       |    122 | M      |
| George     |    122 | M      |
| Adam       |    126 | M      |
| Kimberley  |    132 | F      |
| Fiona      |    133 | F      |
| Bernadette |    133 | F      |
+------------+--------+--------+
```

Comment: I am currently looking at this and trying to adapt it. May be some delay.

Comment: Strawberry, your understanding of my objective is correct. I'm now trying to work out how I adapt it to my slightly more involved code, where I'm ordering by distance between rows/usernames.